# Как посчитать количество элементов

Tags: javascript

Как посчитать количество элементов (цыфер) сколько их, и положительных и отрицательных вмсте? Дано:

```
var a = [-1 ,-2 ,-3 ,-4 ,-5 , 1 ,  2 , 3 , 4 , 5];
 var b;
for(b=0; b<10 ; b++)
{
if (a[b]<0)
{
document.write(a[b]+"<br>")
}
if (a[b]>0)
{
document.write(a[b]+"<br>")
}
}
```

Comment: дело в том, что отрицательных цифр в природе нет. Собственно, как и положительных. А приведенный код выводит положительные и отрицательные числа.

Comment: @KoVadim, положительных/отрицательных цифр - нет, а вот "цыфер" - есть ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тестируем тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/d5P8m/)

```
 var arr = [-1 ,-2 ,-3 ,-4 ,-5 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5],
     positiveN = [],
     negativeN = []; 
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    arr[i] >= 0 ? positiveN.push(arr[i]) : negativeN.push(arr[i]);
}
var result = 'Положительные числа: ' + positiveN.join(',') + 
    ' (количество: ' + positiveN.length + ')<br>' + 
    'Отрицательные числа: ' + negativeN.join(',') +
    ' (количество: ' + negativeN.length + ')';
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [-1 ,-2 ,-3 ,-4 ,-5 , 1 ,  2 , 3 , 4 , 5];
let positive = arr.filter(elem =>(elem <0))
console.log(positive.length)
let negative = arr.filter(elem =>(elem>0))
console.log(negative.length)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @LIBERTY_CONCORD A если массив будет огромный - тоже будете создавать новые массивы только для того, чтобы их длину вывести?